# Pogchamps: How does Michelle Khare beat Pokimane (rook and knight vs rook pair)?

Tags: endgame, rook-and-minor-endgame, fortress, pogchamps

From [pogchamps](https://youtu.be/pkWNpIGUiRY?t=202), specifically [semifinals of consolation bracket of pogchamps 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PogChamps#Consolation_bracket_3):

```
[FEN "4k3/7p/5p2/8/P2rr3/5N2/6PP/4R1K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

[image]

Black (Michelle Khare) just blundered a rook, but white (pokimane) failed to capitalise.

White is currently 1 pawn down but is about to be 2 pawns down so it's basically (rook and) knight vs rook (and rook).

---

Questions:

1. How does black win this? I [tried running in an engine](https://lichess.org/analysis/standard/4k3/7p/5p2/8/P2rr3/5N2/6PP/4R1K1_w_-_-_0_1) and even though it gives black an evaluation of around -1, the evaluation slowly went up to -0.4. Or if it's not really a win for black then how does white draw this?
2. The pawns are on 1 wing. What, if anything, does this mean? Eg more/less likely black will win/white will draw as opposed to pawns on both wings.

---

Note 1: If this turns out to be a fortress or something, then please feel free to edit the tags.

Note 2: This might be covered in [Karsten Müller's endgame series](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35641/practical-endgame-resources-whats-next-after-josh-waitzkins-series-in-chess/36829#36829) probably Volumes 9 or 12, but I think it was covered a bit in Volumes 1, 2 or 4. What I do remember in Volumes 1-4 that might be relevant is that all the pawns are (going to be) on 1 wing.

Note 3: In case it isn't obvious, I'm talking about serious higher level play. A 1500+ in pogchamps should of course win this easily. So what I really mean to ask is how black wins the position, if possible and not *literally* how Michelle Khare beats Pokimane like literally explaining to a 600+ how to beat another 600+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only try to give a very generic and partial answer, since details matter extremely. I shamelessly copy stuff from Müller/Lamprecht "Fundamental Chess Endings".

- Q2 can be answered fully: as always, pawns on different wings means the knight usually loses (being a slower unit than a rook or even a bishop), especially against a rook. Here, they are on one wing, and Black even has a rook pawn, meaning that resacrificing the exchange to win with the last pawn is even harder.
- As always, the weaker side should try to exchange pawns.

  - But note that this is not the all-cure, in the game Reddmann-Müller :-) (RPP-NPP same wing, BCE 7.15) White (the R party) had even to sacrifice a P to convert into a clear win.
  - This means the knight should not land on a "bad circuit", but try its best to hold a fortress. E.g. RP-NP, same line, usually can be hold.
- Zugzwang gives N knightmares. (Sorry.) It is thus the best weapon to break pseudo fortresses.
- Without a P stronghold the N might get chased and ultimately caught.
- Black must try to penetrate with the king from below. For example, White's Kf2/Nf1/Pg2/Ph3 can only be busted by running in via d3-e2.
- Black's pawns are split (disconnected), thus annoying counterattacks are possible if Black tries the former.
- I played blitz with engine suggestions and it seems that Black wins with exactly the suggestions outlined above: White plays h3 and then "nothing". Black protects the bad Ps with the R if necessary, plays a P to h4 (White can never play g3, it frees the f pawn - this also means if White sets up g3-h2 instead of h3-g2, it is even easier to attack by h4), penetrates with the K and keeps the wK encased, and as soon as the bK appears on e3, even f3 is no longer a stronghold for the wN, as Rxf3 always wins.
- Overall: A win with precise Black play, at least Carlsen should convert without problems. White always has too much "holes" to construct a fortress.

Comment: @BCLC that last edit was completely unnecessary, please stop. [*Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.*](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: @Glorfindel: I hope this doesn't hold for typos, those annoy me to the max :-)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann fixing typos is absolutely fine (I do that all the time), and an *occasional* trivial edit isn't that much of a problem either.